# Gradle build variants (like android flavours) for different environments

Tags: java, web-applications, build, gradle, environment-variables

I am trying to build environment dependent artifacts with gradle, especially build different wars for jetty and tomcat with different environments (i.e: jettyDev, jettyStage, jettyProd, tomcatProd)

I've tried [this solution](http://codebrickie.com/blog/2011/04/16/building-for-different-environments-with-gradle/) which works great (only) for properties files. I do know it is possible to create own `configuration`, but it works only for dependencies.

Is there some gradle functionality to build different artifacts with different properties AND dependencies like in android flavours or native variants?

Comment: At least there's this https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/dependency-management-for-jvm-components.md to show that the Gradle folks know that the problem exists.